# C#: Converting unknown object to unknown type when object does not implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, type-conversion

I have object o which has unknown type. I also have a type t to which I want to convert my object.

```
object o = GetExampleObject();
Type t = GetExampleType();
```

When I try to invoke:

```
Convert.ChangeType(o, t);
```

I get error:

> Object must implement IConvertible.

Is there any way to cast it?

Comment: The only way is if you can cast a base class to an inherited class.  You can always cast an variable to an object and then cast an object to a type.  But usually you will get run time errors.  Other way is to use Marshal StructToPtr and PtrToStruct.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. In what situation do you actually have this happening? I'm betting there's a far better way to deal with this than converting unknown types.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators
define how to cast two class

Comment: Also, what is `Convert.Invoke`, what do you expect that function to do? Have you tried using `Convert.ChangeType`? And when you have done a conversion, in what variable will you store the result and how will you actually use it?

Comment: If we remove reflection from the problem, do you have example types and code that would compile, if you could only write the exact types of everything in the code instead? What I mean is, do you have something like `(T)O` cast expression or similar, so that we can see what you're trying to emulate? Do you know if the conversion is even possible, at all?

Comment: @DavidG my mistake. of course i was using ChangeType

Comment: You've answered the lest significant question you've been asked here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to cast object it into `Type` known on the *runtime* only and without `IConvertible` in place, you can create generic static helper method:

```
public static T CastInto<T>(object obj)
{
    return (T)obj; 
    // return obj as T; // if you want to perform safe casting and you are ok with possible null values. Adding type constraint (e.g. where T : class) is needed to use it.
}
```

Then, you must invoke it via reflection:

```
var exampleType = GetExampleType();
MethodInfo castIntoMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("CastInto").MakeGenericMethod(exampleType);

object o = GetExampleObject();
object castedObject = castIntoMethod.Invoke(null, new [] { o });

castedObject.GetType() == exampleType; // true
```

If, there will be finite number of types to which you will convert, I advise you to cache `MethodInfo` objects.

Also, keep in mind that dynamic method invocation is expensive and slow. So you might want to create `Delegate` out of it, using `CreateDelegate` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=netframework-4.8).

Note: As correctly pointed out in the comments, there are many cases in which presented solution won't simply work. So, whenever you have types which are not castable into each other, you will encounter runtime exceptions.

Comment: There are a couple of scenarios where this won't work, e.g. if `obj` is a boxed primitive type (`CastInto<long>(5)` will throw an exception). It also won't work with user-defined conversions, e.g. when converting a `string` to a `XName` (`CastInto<XName>("Test")` will also throw, although `(XName)"Test"` is valid). And `castedObject.GetType() == exampleType` won't necessarily be true.

Comment: ... and where this example is working ... then is useless becuase `castedObject` is `object` ... that's why the question is XY problem

Comment: @Selvin definitely agree with the fact that requirements are not specified correctly. But even if you have `IConvertible`, and if you can use `Convert.ChangeType`, you'll work with `object`, so I don't think that's a particular issue - especially since you don't have to know the type at the compile time.

Comment: If the requirements are not specified correctly, how can you add an answer?

Comment: Also, the example in the fiddle is not correct (`when int i = (int)1.2M; // is working`), because there is no boxing involved, it should be: `int i = (int)((object)1.2M);` - which obviously doesn't work for the same reasons.

Comment: @DavidG do you think all the questions which have answers on SO are correctly defined?